# Give rational with axioms and properties

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A careful solution of $4(x+2)=11$ is given below.

Give the rationale for each step from the ten real number rules $$\{\mathrm{AC},\mathrm{AA},\mathrm{A0},\mathrm{AI},\mathrm{MC},\mathrm{MA},\mathrm{M1},\mathrm{MI},\mathrm{LD},\mathrm{RD}\}$$ and additional rules from $$\{\mathrm{SUB},\mathrm{LCAN},\mathrm{RCAN}\}.$$

That is the question I am addressing, I apologize in advance for this convoluted question as I am new to this stuff. Have mercy

answers = ();

$4(x + 2) = 11$

So.. the proof goes as follows:
 $$
\begin{array}{lll}
1. & 4x + 8  =  11 & \mathrm{LD} \\ 
2. & (4x + 8) - 8 = 11 - 8  & \mathrm{RCAN}  \\
3. & (4x + 8) - 8 = 3 & \mathrm{SUB}  \\
4. & 4x + (8 - 8) = 3 & \mathrm{AA}   \\
5. & 4x + 0 = 3 & \mathrm{AI}  \\
6. & 4x = 3 & \mathrm{A0}  \\
7. & \frac{1}{4}\cdot (4x) = \frac{1}{4}\cdot3 & \mathrm{LCAN}  \\
8. & \frac{1}{4}\cdot (4x) = \frac{3}{4} & \mathrm{SUB}  \\
9. & (\frac{1}{4}\cdot 4)x = \frac{3}{4} & \mathrm{MC}  \\
10. & 1\cdot x = \frac{3}{4} & \mathrm{MI}  \\
11. & x = \frac{3}{4} & \mathrm{M1}  \\
\end{array}
$$
So, those are what I THINK are the answers, but I am having difficulty understand the SUB property. All I can find in my book is that (SUB - substitution) ex. $(4/2 = 2)$ This seems very vague and leads me to believe that the SUB property just means that I can convert the number into different forms without a problem? Or, does it also mean that I can subtract two numbers? OR would I use the additive identities for this subtraction somehow? Any information on this 'SUB' property would be greatly appreciated.

For example, at steps 3 and 8, would this be a form of the SUB property, or is that a branch off of one of the axioms?

$11 - 8$ turns into $3$, is that also SUB? and...
$\frac{1}{4}\cdot 3$ turns into $\frac{3}{4}$

Sorry if this information isn't great, I myself definitely feel that way but that is basically what I am working with. BTW I'm in my first week of precalc.

$\mathrm{AA}$ = cumulative for addition $(a+b)=(b+a) $
$\mathrm{AC}$ = association for addition $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$
$\mathrm{A0}$ = additive identity $a+0=0+a=a $
$\mathrm{AI}$ = additive inverse $a+(-a)=0$

$\mathrm{MC}$ = cumulative for multiplication $ab=ba$
$\mathrm{MA}$ = associative for multiplication $(ab)c = a(bc)$
$\mathrm{M1}$ = multiplicative identity $a+0 = 0+a = a $
$\mathrm{MI}$ = multiplicative inverse $a(a/1) = a$

$\mathrm{LD}$ = left distributive a(b+c) = $ab + ac$
$\mathrm{RD}$ = right distributive (a+b)c = $ac + bc$

$\mathrm{LCAN}$ = left cancellation property $ac = bc$ means $a = b$
$\mathrm{RCAN}$ = right cancellation property $ca = cb$ means $a = b$
$\mathrm{SUB}$ ???? = substitution principle: if two numbers are equal, then syntactically we can replace one with the other $(4/2) = 2$

Comment: I will point out that LCAN and RCAN are false without the added stipulation that $c\neq 0$.  $5\cdot 0 = 2\cdot 0$ does not imply that $5=2$.  As for your question, going from eq 2 to eq 3 is done by evaluating $11-8$, i.e. SUB.  Going from eq 3 to eq 4 is a result of the associative property for addition.  $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$.  Similarly, going from eq 7 to 8, $3\cdot \frac{1}{4}$ turns into $\frac{3}{4}$ as per how multiplication is defined for fractions of real numbers.  $a=\frac{a}{1}$ and $\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{c}{d}=\frac{ac}{bd}$ so $\frac{1}{4}\cdot 3 = \frac{3}{4}$, so yes also SUB.

Comment: Cumulative? Do you mean **commutative**?